# Can I use Logical OR(||) operator instead of Logical AND(&&) operator

Tags: c, operators

This is what I code for program which do case conversion of string :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXp9w.png

I'm confused why I can't use Logical OR (`||`) operator instead of Logical AND(`&&`)operator in line `if(str[i]>='a'&& str[i]<='z')`

Comment: They mean completely different things. Why would you expect them to be interchangeable?

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots. See here for more info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Because both conditions need to be true in order to satisfy your intent. If you use `||`, then as long as `'z' > 'a'` then any value will satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other possible characters after `'z'` and below `'a'` ([ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)), so it's necessary to do both upper and lower bounds checks with `&&`. If you used the `||` operator then the statement could execute if the character were *any* value, because ALL characters are greater than `'a'` or less than `'z'`.